# Can I bring that question over here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic, appropriate-questions

I have this naming / terminology question which I first posted on "Code Review" and then it was moved to "Programmers" and then it was closed.  Would it be appropriate for "English", after some editing to make it more friendly to non-programmers?

This is the question on Programmers.StackExchange: [Need help with naming (marshaling interface calls)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/126194/need-help-with-naming-marshaling-interface-calls)

**Update:** I posted it on EL&U: [Synonyms for multiplexing and demultiplexing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53683/synonyms-for-multiplexing-and-demultiplexing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm just one person, but I think it'd be off topic because we don't accept questions about naming methods/interfaces/functions etc--they usually end up as being too localized because you probably have some constraints that make them applicable to a very small subset of the ELU population.

Comment: That's what I would think, but then I saw this question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46867/word-for-application-that-is-both-sender-and-receiver so I thought it might not be so off topic afterall.

Comment: What I am trying to say is that if I was to bring it over here I would dress it in a context understandable by non-programmers.

Comment: That question isn't naming a method, though--just trying to describe the program in general without the same constraints imposed on methods.

Comment: I think it would be closed fairly quickly--the context of being an interface name is important because it imposes a constraint; at the same time this constraint makes the question very un-universally applicable

Comment: OK --tell you what: I will delete this question, then I will go and edit that question of mine, and then I will repost this question, so that it is easier for you to judge.

Comment: Instead of deleting and reposting, you can leave this one open, post the question on EL&U, and see what happens.

Comment: OK. I guess I should not be so downvotophobic. (If you would excuse the word.)

Comment: @MikeNakis This is the meta site for a Stack Exchange 2.0 site; you don't lose or gain reputation on the meta site, if your posts get voted. I don't see the reason for down-voting this question, though, as it is not implying the question in question is surely acceptable.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I was not referring to downvotes here. By following simchona's advice I will be posting my original question to EL&U, and risk the chance of it being downvoted there. Those are the downvotes I was afraid of. But it is okay, I will do it, and come what may.

Comment: I posted it: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53683/synonyms-for-multiplexing-and-demultiplexing